# CSS Padding/Border Question

Tags: css

This is driving me crazy. Can anyone tell me what I am missing here.

I have a word-press site I am trying to copy the design into an e-commerce skin
The wordpress site: http://solesu.clarityproductions.com/ and the
e-commerce skin i am working on is http://cspro.solesu.com/.

The words MAIN PAGE are slightly differently balanced from the wordpress site to the 
e-commerce skin and I cant figure it out. Can anyone help me where the problem
is and what css change may need to be made. I have been looking a this for hours.

It looks like the background padding or height or something is a little taller
on top and bottom on the wordpress site but im not sure whats controlling this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is a quite a few differences in the code. Have you tried using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox or the Webkit Developer Tools to inspect the page elements for differences?

After a quick look I can see that your missing elements and other stuff is going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have on line 54 in your `styles.css`:

```
.sidebox-categories-wrapper ul li a, x:-webkit-any-link, x:default {
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

It's the `padding-bottom: 3px;` that expands the height of the anchor tag.

Remove it, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is the style giving you the issue

```
.sidebox-categories-wrapper ul li a, x:-webkit-any-link, x:default {
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

just make sure you overwrite it

```
#vmenu_8 a {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

And it'll be fine.